# Sphinxsearch Sorting and Ranking

Tags: sorting, sphinx, ranking

What is the difference between Sorting and Ranking in sphinxsearch?

I've recently implemented sphinxsearch in my application.. I see that sphinx offers sorting which is really good. But there is also Set Ranking mode.. I don't clearly understand the difference between sorting and ranking..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranking compute a rank

Sorting is like order by

you can order by rank, attribute, id,....